# Create dynamic sitemap from text file using php

Tags: php, html

I have to create a dynamic site map for a uni assignment using PHP.

I have saved the names of the links in a text file called "sitemap.txt". These names are the names of the pages minus their extensions and I am supposed to use this content to generate a link. The content looks like this:

Index,Services,Contact Us,Register,Login,Class Manager

My code is below:

```
        <?php
                $fp = fopen("sitemap.txt", "r");
                echo '<p class="smallerText">';
                while(!feof($fp))
                {
                    $line = fgets($fp);
                    $array = explode(",", $line);
                }
                fclose($fp);
                $num_elements = count($array);

                $list = '<ul class="servicesList" name="sitemap">';

                for($count = 0; $count < $num_elements; $count++)
                {
                    $list .= "<li>$array[$count]</li>"; 
                }
                $list .= "</ul>";

                echo "$list";
            ?>
```

So basically I have been able to print the contents of the file to the page without any issues. But I need to convert the static text into links.

Can anyone suggest a way? I was thinking using regex or string matching but I'm not sure how.

Comment: How are you supposed to know where to link to? Also, you could look into the function `foreach` to make looping over arrays simpler. (`for` works fine, but at least imo `foreach` is more readable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are asking, but if it's creating link out of those names, can't you just ....

```
$YourDomain="http://mydomain.com/";
$ext=".php";
for($count = 0; $count < $num_elements; $count++)
                {
                    $list .= "<li><a href=\"$YourDomain.$array[$count].$ext\">$array[$count]</a></li>"; 
                }
```

Comment: thats exactly what I need to do...I was really over thinking this! My only issue with that is that I have a mixture of .php and .html extensions. Could I use some sort of tag in the text file to differentiate between which ones are .html and which are .php?

Comment: yes, you can use some kind of identification..like adding #1, #2 to denote different extension to the file name and can identify and filter them here